# TikTok Direct post API - On status check not giving the correct publish ID

Tags: tiktok, tiktok-api

We have implemented TikTok direct posting API to publish the video directly on the TikTok personal account.

When we hit the post status check API through Axios to check the status of the video, it gives us a publish ID, which does not exist on TikTok, but if we hit the same API through Postman, it returns a different publish ID which is exists.

Postman Curl Call

```
curl --location 'https://open.tiktokapis.com/v2/post/publish/status/fetch/' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <access-token>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '
{
   "publish_id": "<Publish_ID>"
}'
```

Same way we are hitting the API through code.